# How to do fast flicker text or simply replace text faster in html(My code is below)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to replace bunch of words in the single div using this code but its so slow and blinks i want it like fast, that user can see it's changing but can't read it properly because it'll be fast. (I've also tried reducing miliseconds but it results showing same word again and again) Please help

```js
(function(){
  var words = ['awesome','incredible','cool','fantastic','function',
'words','var','script','html','fadeOut','body','fadeIn','length','creative','drama',
  ], i = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
    $('#changerificwordspanid').fadeOut(function(){
      $(this).html(words[i=(i+2)%words.length]).fadeIn();
    });
  }, 1000);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="changerificwordspanid">awesome</span>
```

Comment: I already said that it's just repeating and stuck to same word again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the logic for getting a different word, and adjust the timing for the `fadeOut`

```js
var words = [
    'awesome',
    'incredible',
    'cool',
    'fantastic',
    'function',
    'words',
    'var',
    'script',
    'html',
    'fadeOut',
    'body',
    'fadeIn',
    'length',
    'creative',
    'drama',
  ],
  i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  i = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)
  $('#changerificwordspanid').html(function() {    
    $(this).html(words[i]).show();
  });
}, 100);
```

```html
<span id="changerificwordspanid">awesome</span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

hope this helps

```js
(function() {
  var words = ['awesome', 'incredible', 'cool', 'fantastic', 'function', 'words', 'var', 'script', 'html', 'fadeOut', 'body', 'fadeIn', 'length', 'creative',
      'drama',
    ],
    i = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#changerificwordspanid').html(function() {
      $(this).html(words[i = (i + 2) % words.length]).fadeIn();
    });
  }, 50);


})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <span id="changerificwordspanid">awesome</span>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `html()` or `text()` with decreasing the interval. Also the `fadeIn()` is really meaningless with such interval:

```js
(function(){
  var words = ['awesome','incredible','cool','fantastic','function',
'words','var','script','html','fadeOut','body','fadeIn','length','creative','drama',
  ], i = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
    $('#changerificwordspanid').text(function(){
      $(this).text(words[i=(i+2)%words.length]);
    });
  }, 100);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="changerificwordspanid">awesome</span>
```

Comment: You're fantastic bro :) Such a genius :) Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Another possiblity would be to use `setTimeout()` to iterate the list of words. This has the advantage of presenting the next word when the browser is ready, rather than to force updates on a fixed interval.

You could even generalise this functionality into a reusable JQuery plugin as shown below:

```js
// Define a reusable jquery plugin
$.fn.flicker = function(list) {
  
  // Track state for this flicker locally
  let i = 0;
  let self = this;
  
  function doIteration() {

    // Increment the counter and update the element text
    i++;
    self.text(list[i % list.length]);

    // Invoke next iteration after 100ms
    setTimeout(doIteration, 100);
  }

  // Start the flicker for this element
  doIteration();
  return this;
} 

// Origianl example
$('#changerificwordspanid').flicker([
  'awesome',
  'incredible',
  'cool',
  'fantastic',
  'function',
  'words',
  'var',
  'script',
  'html',
  'fadeOut',
  'body',
  'fadeIn',
  'length',
  'creative',
  'drama',
]);

// Example usage of flicker on another element with different list
$('#other').flicker([
  'foo',
  'bar'
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="changerificwordspanid">awesome</span>
<hr/>
<span id="other">awesome</span>
```

Comment: Wow so awesome. Thank you for suggesting this idea. :) Can i use this code?

Comment: You're welcome - yes please feel free to use it :-)